Confused by formatting requirements of a journal
I intend to submit my first research paper to European Sport Management Quarterly but I'm really confused about the instructions.

Manuscripts should be compiled in the following order: title page;
abstract; keywords; main text; acknowledgements; references;
appendices (as appropriate); table(s) with caption(s) (on individual
pages); figure caption(s) (as a list).

when it says Tables with captions should be a section, does it mean I have to refrain from inserting them in the main text and just show them in its own specific section or it is Ok to also include them in the text?


Tables with captions should be a section, does it mean I have to refrain from inserting them in the main text and just show them in its own specific section

Yes, that's correct; they'll be in their own section. You will refer to the table in the main text but the table itself and its caption will be separate. Same for figures.
This is a typical submission format. Yeah, it's stupid, but also standard. Normally the final paper will be assembled differently, this format is just for the submission.

Thank you, sir. Figures/images are fine to be included in the main text then according to the instructions, right? I just have to write the captions of the figures in a different section.

@MmdLyon Hmm, I guess that's unclear. In my experience they are most often separate, but the text you include here does not actually specify the location of the figures themselves. It is likely there is an entirely separate section of the submission process to add the figures, and they probably do not want them in the manuscript document at all. That would be most consistent with my typical experience. Look for the "instructions to authors" page on the journal website and read through them carefully; for a shortcut, do a search for the word "figure" and see what they say.

Yes, at https://www.tandfonline.com/action/authorSubmission?journalCode=resm20&page=instructions#mp_figures see "Figures must be saved separate to text. Please do not embed figures in the manuscript file." - there are then further instructions for how to format figures.

Yes, I missed that part. Thanks again. have a good day.
